# Our app is due to QUERY_ ALL_ The PACKAGES permission has been removed from the shelf

Tags: android, google-play

[image]

We have removed this permission, but it is still off the shelf.

Issue found: Less broad app-visibility method should be used
We are unable to approve your app’s use of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission because the declared task can be done with a less broad app-visibility method.

One suggested method is to declare your app's need for specific package visibility using the element. You may refer to the common use cases.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 4400012
SPLIT_BUNDLE 4400018
About the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission Policy
The QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission cannot be used in the following scenario:
When the required task can be done with a less broad app-visibility method.
The QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission can be used in the following scenario:
When your app’s core user-facing functionality or purpose requires discovering any and all installed apps on the device for awareness or interoperability purposes. Examples include device search, antivirus apps, file managers, and browsers.
Note: Apps granted access to this permission must comply with the User Data policies, including Prominent Disclosure and Consent Requirement, and may not extend its use to undisclosed or invalid purposes.
For more help addressing this issue, read more in our Help Center.

If you believe that your use case is policy compliant, please contact our policy support team and provide the following details:

An explanation of why the required task cannot be completed with a less broad app-visibility method, and
Code excerpts (in an text file attachment) of where QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission is used in your app, and/or
If your app is using any SDKs requiring the use of the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, provide SDK documentation (in the form of a screenshot or an accessible link) describing the use case for each of the SDKs using the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission

Our app has removed this permission, but it is still off the shelf. However, according to the email information, it should be caused by the historical version, but we can't make the historical version off the shelf. It seems that this is an unsolvable problem.

I suspected that the third-party library used this library, but I analyzed our apk package through Android Studio and checked your manifest file. I didn't find this permission, nor did I find this file in the compilation folder.